# How to find scrollTop after DOM modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I am working on mobile application, we use AJAX to load pages based on the Framework7, but since I'm loading pages & content dynamically, my function supposed to change the header's color is not working anymore.

here is my fonction :

```
function scroller(){ 
    var target=$(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(target);

    if(target>=150){
        $('.navbar').css({'background-color':'rgba(191, 141, 87, 1)', 'box-shadow':'0px 0px 5px black', 'transition': 'all 1s ease'});
    }
    else{
        $('.navbar').css({'background-color':'rgba(191, 141, 87, 0)','box-shadow':'none'});
    }   
}
```

The console is displaying 0 for var target, and I guess this is because I modify DOM and add content that is not here at the instanciation of the page.

How can I make my function work ? Thanks

EDIT :

I call my function in the body :

```
<body onscroll="scroller();">
```

Comment: Using AJAX to load data would have no effect on the logic you've shown. It may affect how you call `scroller()` itself though - can you edit your question to include that code.

Comment: Some clients/browsers have trouble with `scrollTop` when certain styles are manipulated for the `body` or `html` elements. Are you setting `height` or `overflow` styles on either of those elements?

Comment: Why do you write two `$` signs... like `$$('.navbar')`

Comment: @lumio this is because I'm using Framework7, they got their own DOM library, and to not conflict it with Jquery they are using $$ instead of $

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarification. What you can do on the other hand is, to toggle a class if target is working again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below example i hope you want like this...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kecahyk3/4/)

```js
function scroller(){ 
    var target=$(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(target);

    if(target>=150){
        $('.navbar').css({'background-color':'rgba(191, 141, 87, 1)', 'box-shadow':'0px 0px 5px black', 'transition': 'all 1s ease'});
    }
    else{
        $('.navbar').css({'background-color':'gold','box-shadow':'none'});
    }   
}   
 $(document).scroll(function(){
  scroller();
 })
```

```css
.navbar{
  position:fixed;top:0;background-color: gold;width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <p>
    Header...
  </p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
   <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should add a bit of explanation.

Comment: The function is toggled when the scroll top is higher than 150, then change it back when it's below 150

Comment: Now run the above snippet you will find your answer.